# Aligning overflow scroll with picture height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

bit noob here, but hope someone could help.
I have a left hand side picture that occupies 2/3 of a flexbox div, and a text div on the right hand side that occupies 1/3.

How can i get the right hand side div to follow the height of the left hand side picture, so that overflow scroll ends in line with the bottom of the picture, even when resizing the viewport.

My current code is below, but this only looks ok at one size.

Appreciate any feedback.

Richard

```css
approach-wrapper {
  display: flex;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.approach-wrapper img { 
 width:100%;
}

.approach-wrapper .section-left {
 width: 66%;
 height: 100%;
}

.approach-wrapper .section-right {
  width: 34%;
  height:605px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  overflow:auto;
 }
 
.approach-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="approach-wrapper">
 <div class="section-left">
  <img alt="test" src="img/picture.jpg" /> </div>
 <div class="section-right approach-content">
  <p>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
  Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there was mistake in your css (.) dot is missing for class `approach-wrapper` in your css and also i have removed height for **left** and **right** class as there is no need for height.

```css
.approach-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.approach-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}

.approach-wrapper .section-left {
  width: 66%;
}

.approach-wrapper .section-right {
  width: 34%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.approach-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="approach-wrapper">
  <div class="section-left">
    <img alt="test" src="img/picture.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="section-right approach-content">
    <p>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br> Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br> Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>      Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Loads of text12345678910<br> Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br> Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>      Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br> Loads of text12345678910<br>Loads of text12345678910<br></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this does not work. Right hand side does not scroll on overflow, but rather dictates the whole height for the wrapper.